# Encontrar la palabra en orden

Tags: python, string, bucle-for

En Python necesito saber si una palabra en específico se puede formar con las letras de un texto y éste se debe recorrer en orden.

Es decir, la frase

```
Mientras sufría de sarampión asaba nueces en el magosto.
```

Quiero encontrar dentro de esta frase la palabra `Saramago`, pero no vale solo decir si las letras están en la frase o no, sino que se debe recorrer la frase y encontrar la primera letra, la `s`, luego la `a`, pero ésta ya no puede estar antes de la `s` encontrada en la frase, la idea es decir si se puede formar la palabra completa dentro del texto.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenida a la comunidad, te recomiendo visitar la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea más clara y puedas ganar tu primer medalla. Por favor agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora para poderte ayudar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Además de dar algún detalle más que ayude a clarificar el problema, da alguna explicación de las etiquetas que usas. Con la etiqueta [tag:bucle-for] das a entender que buscas una solución que use _bucles for_ por algún motivo, lo que limitaría las posibles soluciones.

Comment: Una alternativa sería mediante regex. Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo aquí el código. Te recomiendo que si tienes problemas de este estilo, sigas practicando ejercicios similares sin consultar ayuda directa sobre el ejercicio, para que en el futuro lo puedas sacar sin ninguna ayuda. Si necesitas cualquier cosa, o no entiendes muy bien como se hace, avísalo.

```
def palabra_en_frase(frase, palabra):
    frase = frase.lower()  # Pasamos la frase a minusculas
    palabra = palabra.lower()  # Pasamos la palabra a minusculas
    for letra in frase:  # Recorremos de letra en letra la frase
        if letra == palabra[0]:  # Si la letra coincide con la primera letra de la palabra, hacemos lo siguiente:
            palabra = palabra[1:]  # Quitamos la primera letra a la palabra para que ahora compare la siquiente letra
            if len(palabra) == 0:  # Si ya no quedan mas letras en la palabra, lo conseguimos
                return True  # Enviamos que lo hemos conseguido
    return False  # Si llegamos a este punto significa que ya hemos recorrido toda la frase sin encontrar la palabra


entrada = 'Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto.'
objetivo = 'Saramago'

print('La palabra esta en la frase.' if palabra_en_frase(entrada, objetivo) else 'La palabra no esta en la frase')
```

Comment: Hola. Buena respuesta y explicación. Recuerda que si la persona que realiza la pregunta no añade ni siquiera una muestra de que ha intentado algo la respuesta podría ser votada negativa por otras personas.

Comment: Entendido. Soy nuevo en esto y no sabía si sería correcto publicar el problema ya resuelto de lo que parece un ejercicio de clase. Entonces en estos casos, ¿qué se debería de  hacer?. Gracias por avisar.

Comment: @cls Yo lo que suelo hacer en estos casos es explicar "de palabra" cómo se resolvería el problema y en ocasiones incluso con algo de pseudocódigo, indicando al OP que con eso debería tener suficiente para intentar implementarlo él mismo y que pregunte de nuevo si se atasca, pero esta vez ya con dudas más concretas.

Comment: @abulafia me lo apunto para la próxima vez. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Mariana te explico más o menos el siguiente código, que según he probado funciona, a ver si lo puedes adaptar más exactamente a lo que deseas. Primero convertimos tanto el texto como la palabra a buscar a minúsculas mediante el `método lower()` (aunque también podríamos hacerlo pasándolo a mayúsculas con el `método upper()`), de esta manera podremos ir comparando los caracteres que forma cada cadena sin que se cree conflicto , pues python es sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas.
Usaremos la variable j para recorrer el texto, la inicializamos a 0, ya que las estructuras complejas en python siempre empiezan en 0, y a demás necesitamos que tenga un valor antes de ser usada en el `bucle while` para evaluar la condición.

Procedemos a hacer un `bucle for` que irá recorriendo cada carácter de la palabra indicada, es por ello que la variable que la recorre (i) tomará valores desde 0 hasta el tamaño de la palabra. En cada vuelta dada nos encontramos con un `bucle while` en el cual entraremos cuando el carácter de la palabra no coincida con el carácter del texto, y cuando no hayamos terminado de recorrer el texto. Así pues si entramos en el bucle es porque el carácter de la palabra no coincide con el del texto y por ello aumentamos el valor de j para pasar al siguiente carácter del texto.
Una vez salimos del `bucle while` comprobamos con el `if` si la finalización del bucle se debe a que ha sido encontrada la letra en el texto o porque hemos terminado de recorrerlo y no hemos encontrado la letra buscada. En caso de ser por este último motivo, cambiamos la variable esta a False y con un `break` salimos de la estructura.
Por último en base a la variable esta indicamos el éxito de la búsqueda o bien la imposibilidad y la letra por la cual ha sido imposible.

Cualquier duda no dudes en preguntarme, un saludo y mucha suerte!

```
    texto = 'Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto.'
    palabra = 'Saramago'
    texto = texto.lower()
    palabra = palabra.lower()
    esta = True
    j = 0
    letra_texto = texto[j]
    for i in range(0, len(palabra)):
        while ((palabra[i] != letra_texto) and (j < len(texto) -1)):
            j += 1
            letra_texto = texto[j]
        
        if palabra[i] != letra_texto:
            esta = False
            break;
            
    if esta: 
        print('{palabra_buscada} si se puede formar'.format(palabra_buscada = palabra))
    else:
        print('Hemos recorrido el texto y no se encuentran el caracter {caracter}'.format(caracter = palabra[i]))
```

Comment: Aunque se agradece la intención, procura no responder a preguntas en donde el OP (autor de la pregunta) no haya mostrado lo que ha intentado. Recuerda que [es.so] _no es un servicio de código_. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.